# Dual Rail Switch Mode Power Supply Filtering

Tags: switch-mode-power-supply, emi-filtering

I'm looking at the datasheet for a dual rail SMPS I plan on using for analog circuits, and I'm wondering about how to interpret some recommended filtering circuits. I understand a simple filtering suggestion for the dual rail versions of this SMPS, shown here:

[image]

My analog ICs are noise sensitive, so I want to use more rigorous filtering than just input and output capacitors. The datasheet gives another filtering recommendation I plan on implementing:

[image]

On the output of the SMPS, should I use two output capacitors instead of the one shown in the datasheet, connecting them from the positive and negative supplies to the output ground? Also, will using a dual rail SMPS change the connections of CY1 and CY2? Note that the datasheet gives this second circuit as being an "EMC Recommended Circuit."

The full datasheet for this device is [here](https://www.cui.com/product/resource/pdqe10-d.pdf)

Comment: What analog IC are you refering as noise sensitive?

Comment: AD600. At 1MHz PSRR is around 20 dB

Comment: The second circuit does not add filtering for circuits connected to the output. The second circuit adds filtering on the input side to prevent noise generated by the p.s. from flowing back into the source and creating emi.